# yii catch cdbexception on insert

Tags: php, yii

I want to catch db exception on insert (like foreign key or duplicate exception).

```
try {       
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->insert('table1', array(
                'sid'=>$sid,
                'val1'=>$val1
                ));
        } catch (CDbException  $e) {
            die();
        }
```

But the command throw an exception before I catch it.

```
...\framework\db\CDbCommand.php(358)

346         {
347             if($this->_connection->enableProfiling)
348                 Yii::endProfile('system.db.CDbCommand.execute('.$this->getText().$par.')','system.db.CDbCommand.execute');
349 
350             $errorInfo=$e instanceof PDOException ? $e->errorInfo : null;
351             $message=$e->getMessage();
352             Yii::log(Yii::t('yii','CDbCommand::execute() failed: {error}. The SQL statement executed was: {sql}.',
353                 array('{error}'=>$message, '{sql}'=>$this->getText().$par)),CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR,'system.db.CDbCommand');
354 
355             if(YII_DEBUG)
356                 $message.='. The SQL statement executed was: '.$this->getText().$par;
357 
358             throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: {error}',
359                 array('{error}'=>$message)),(int)$e->getCode(),$errorInfo);
360         }
361     }
```

Comment: what exception it throwing?

Comment: Please provide real example with out cuts and full exception message.

Comment: for the moment, it throwing a duplicate exception. I got the same if I use command.execute($insertQuery). I need to found a way that the command not Throwing an exception, just return an exception, I will work with the exception by myself.